# Why does two servers connect the same NIC when I use bonding in Linux with mode=6?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, ethernet, bonding

I create a bonding interface with 3 NICs in CentOS6.3. I use mode=6, which doesn't need the hardware support of the switch.

Here is the bonding file:

```
[root@~]cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0 
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.6.0 (September 26, 2009)

Bonding Mode: adaptive load balancing
Primary Slave: None
Currently Active Slave: eth3
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0

Slave Interface: eth1
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 1
Permanent HW addr: 00:e0:66:d3:70:b1
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: eth2
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 1
Permanent HW addr: 00:e0:66:d3:70:b2
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: eth3
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 1
Permanent HW addr: 00:e0:66:d3:70:b3
Slave queue ID: 0
```

I use three Windows server to connect the bonding IP. In theory, each server will get a different MAC address. For example, Server 1 will connect to eth1, and Server 2 will connect to eth2, and Server 3 will connect to eth3. Then the load will be balanced.

However, Server 1 connects to eth2, and Server 2 connects to eth3, but Server 3 connects to eth2 again. eth1 is never used. I have tried many times but failed. Finally I manually binds the IP address and the MAC address together to solve this problem.

Why does this happen? Is there a way to make every NIC is used? There are only three servers are connected, so in theory each server should connect to a different NIC.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made the assumption:

> each server will get a different MAC address. For example, Server 1 will connect to eth1, and Server 2 will connect to eth2, and Server 3 will connect to eth3.

However that is not correct. As per [the Linux kernel bonding documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/bonding.txt):

> different peers use different hardware addresses

But not *every* peer *will* use a different hardware address.

The load balancing algorithm is based around a hash table, you need to use more than three hosts on the same broadcast domain to achieve equal load balancing across all slaves.

If you had a large number of hosts communicating with your bond, say tens or hundreds of hosts on the same broadcast domain, then the number of hosts would be fairly equal across all bond slaves.

For the sort of load balancing you're after, you might be better using Mode 2 or Mode 4 with `xmit_hash_policy` set to `layer2+3` or `layer3+4`, however that will only do transmit load balancing, it would be up to the switch to provide similar inbound load balancing.

(Note: `layer3+4` is not compatible with Mode 4, your switch may or may not complain if it is configured that way, try it and see)

Really, if you want your three Windows systems to communicate with your Linux system over different interfaces, then the only 100% reliable way to do this is to separate the interfaces at Layer 2 - have each of your eth1/eth2/eth3 in a different VLAN with a different IP, and the Windows systems each know the Linux system by that different IP.